# Text file only found when running outside of Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, file-io

I've got an a project (native C++ compiled to .exe) that runs fine outside of VS 2010, but inside of VS (with or without the debugger) it gets stuck trying to find a text file located in the same bin folder as it.

Any ideas as to why this would happen? My hunch is that VS messes with where the code looks when trying to open a file, but I don't know enough details to correct this.

**Some details:**

My .exe calls a function from a .dll I wrote earlier, which in turn tries to find a text file specifying that function's parameters. For convenience I've placed all of these files in the same folder, so finding the text file wouldn't be a problem.

Before opening the file, the function checks that it exists using:

```
PersistentAssert(Utility::FileExists(Filename), "Parameter file not found");
```

In VS 2010 this line causes "Parameter file not found" to display, but outside of VS the program manages to find the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When launching an executable from visual studio by default it uses the project file directory as the current working directory. You can change it in Configuration Properties -> Debugging -> Working Directory.

However I don't think it's correct behavior to search your programs datafiles etc from the current working directory. Instead your program should find out the directory of the executable and find the files in that directory.

Comment: Wow, an even more explicit answer. I've got to ask questions on these tags more often...

Answer (score 1):

Processes have the concept of a "current directory", which may or may not be the same directory as where the `.exe` file is located. It sounds like when you run your program inside VS, the current directory is something other than where your `.exe` is.

Somewhere in the project settings, there should be a place where you can choose what directory will be the current directory when your program starts inside the debugger. Set that to the same location as your `.exe` and you should be good.

Comment: That was it exactly -- fastest SO answer ever. Thankies!